# How to create the Native 64bit installer with Advanced-Installer

Tags: installation, registry, 64-bit, advanced-installer

my installer.exe is created with advanced installer 9.6.1, and the package type is amd64.
but when i run it in windows 7 64bit, it run as 32mode, the registry key is write in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\, but the software is Native 64bit application,so it cannot get the registry keys.

so i want know: how to create the Native 64bit installer.exe or write the registry in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE, not WOW6432NODE.

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-32-64-bit-registry.html

Comment: Very thanks, i resolved it. in "Organization" page, set the registry key is 64-bit Component, it's OK.